# Laravel Nested Foreach for FAQ Views Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, foreach, nested

i have a problem with my FAQ views. i want to display FAQ by categories like this:

Category1

- FAQ1
- FAQ2
- FAQ3

Category2

- FAQ1
- FAQ2
- FAQ3

Here is my **Controller**

```
public function faq()
    {
        $faq_category_vendor = DB::table('faq_categories')->where('categories_for','1')->get();
        $faq_vendor = DB::table('faqs')
                        ->join('faq_categories', 'faq_categories.id', '=', 'faqs.category')
                        ->select('faqs.*','faq_categories.*', 'faq_categories.id as idcategory', 'faqs.id as id')
                        ->where('faq_for','1')->get();
        return view('owner.faq',['faq_category_vendor' => $faq_category_vendor,'faq_vendor' => $faq_vendor]);
    }
```

Here is my **Views** :

```
@foreach($faq_category_vendor as $item)
                For ({{$item->name}}) :
                @foreach($faq_vendor as $item2)
                  @if ($item->id == $item2->category)
                  - {{$item2->ask}} : {{$item2->answer}}<br>
                  @else
                  @endif
                @endforeach
                <br>
              @endforeach
```

The output is :

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'category' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\weddinc\weddinc\weddinc_beta\resources\views\owner\faq.blade.php)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried using `$item['category']` instead?

Comment: in views? line 1, 2 or 4?

Comment: In your controller function `faq()`, put this just before `return` statement `dd(faq_category_vendor)`. Then update your question with the output of `dd`.

Comment: @Alex $item2['category'] no? But, why should it be an array.

Comment: @linuxartisan i have update my controller to `return view('owner.faq',['dd(faq_category_vendor)' => $faq_category_vendor,'faq_vendor' => $faq_vendor]);` and my views to `@foreach(dd as $item)` but still not working.

Comment: @AbuUbaidillah Nooooo. I said, put the `dd(faq_category_vendor)` statement _before_ `return`.

Comment: @linuxartisan still error `Use of undefined constant faq_category_vendor - assumed 'faq_category_vendor' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)`

Comment: You certainly have no idea of the `dd` function. Just change your controller function like so `...   ->where('faq_for','1')->get();   dd($faq_category_vendor);    return view('owner.fa ... `. Sorry for not typing the `$` sign before the variable name.

Comment: im sorry about that, this my controller & still not working `$faq_category_vendor = DB::table('faq_categories')->where('categories_for','1')->get();
        $faq_vendor = DB::table('faqs')
                        ->join('faq_categories', 'faq_categories.id', '=', 'faqs.category')
                        ->select('faqs.*','faq_categories.*', 'faq_categories.id as idcategory', 'faqs.id as id')
                        ->where('faq_for','1')->get();
        dd(faq_category_vendor);
        return view('owner.faq',['faq_category_vendor' => $faq_category_vendor,'faq_vendor' => $faq_vendor]);`

Comment: The variable `$item2` does not have a 'category' - this usually means that $item2 is not what you think it is. Underneath your line `@foreach($faq_vendor as $item2)` can you please post the output of `{{ dd($item2) }}` so that we can check if that is what you expected it to be?

Comment: @AbuUbaidillah It's `dd($faq_category_vendor);`. Note that `$` sign. Then you'll get some output in the browser. Show us that output.

Comment: @linuxartisan the output is `Collection {#488 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#494 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"categories_for": 1
      +"name": "Akun"
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
    1 => {#137 ▼
      +"id": 4
      +"categories_for": 1
      +"name": "Pembayaran"
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: @AbuUbaidillah Do you notice that there is no _key_ named `category` in the array? You are trying to access `$item2->category`. That is why you are getting the error.

Comment: @AbuUbaidillah Oh! Just realised one thing. You need to `dd` this `dd($faq_vendor);`. Paste the output here.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your faq_categories has id in faqs,becouse if don't you will get empty join so trying get

```
$item2->category
```

will throw exception.My proposition is do something like this in .blade

```
@php
 try{
   $testData=$item2->category;
 } throw (\Exception $e) {
   dd($item2);
 }
@endphp
```

That will give you dd in blade so you will see if all records has joins

Answer (score 0):

So there's a couple of points here which will help you out.

Your controller implies that you don't have relationships set up. Having relationships between your data will help you out massively; from what I can make out, you have a 1 to many relationship between faq_categories and faq (one faq_category has many faqs).

So, in your FaqCategory model:

```
public function faqs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('app\faq');
}
```

In your Faq model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('app\faq_category`);
}
```

Okay, so you said that you want to display each category, and then each FAQ under every category. In your controller, you can get all categories like so:

`$categories = FaqCategory::all();`

And in your blade, you can do this:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach($category->faqs as $faq)
         {{ $faq }}
    @endforeach
@enforeach
```

Comment: thats great, its work for me, whats :D [https://www.yukampus.com](https://www.yukampus.com)